# How to open telnet as a textfile rather than a binary file

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

So I was trying to use the read_until method in telnet but then ran into the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Desktop\7DTD Bot\test.py", line 44, in <module>
tn.read_until("Please enter password:")
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", 
line 302, in read_until
i = self.cookedq.find(match)
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

I'm almost sure that this is because the telnet is being opened as a binary file rather than as a text file. Here's how I opened it in the first place:

```
HOST = config.get("telnet", "telnet_host")
PORT = config.get("telnet", "telnet_port")
PASS = config.get("telnet", "telnet_pass")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT)
tn.read_until("Please enter password:")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the `PORT` should be of type `int` or a `bytes-like` object.  Currently it is type `str`. Convert the `PORT` variable to an `int` like this.

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, int(PORT))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it but I just converted the string to a bytestring to fix this problem:

```
tn.read_until(b"Please enter password:")
```

And also thanks for the minus one!