# python telnetlib.telnet() not connecting using variables

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am working on a script to pull configs from Cisco devices in GNS3. The script should be looping through a text file and slicing the IP & Port from each line into variables.  These variable are then fed into the telnet connection as the IP & Port parameters of `Telnetlib`.

```
import telnetlib

#Open file with list of switches
f = open ("C:\ProgramData\ports.txt")

#Telnet to each switch and configure it
for line in f:
    linePort = line[10:]
    lineIP = line[:-6]
    print "Getting running-config " + lineIP + " " + linePort
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(lineIP,linePort)
```

However using the variables always ends up in an error being thrown (see below) but if I hard code the same values I am able to create the connection without issue.  As it works with a hard coded value I tried forcing a string type with `str()` on the two variables but it didn't change the result and it still throws the below error.

```
C:\Users\SomeUser>python %userprofile%\desktop\config.py
Getting running-config 127.0.0.1  5000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\desktop\config.py", line 11, in <module>
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(lineIP,linePort)
  File "C:\python27amd64\lib\telnetlib.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\python27amd64\lib\telnetlib.py", line 227, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\python27amd64\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed
```

The error being thrown is `socket.gaierrr: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed` which I have tried looking into but have not been able to find a resolution for that works for me.  Given that this process is supposed to be automated and in a loop it is vital to get it working with variable.  As such any help that you all could provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657406/how-to-open-telnet-as-a-textfile-rather-than-a-binary-file) to this in another question and it makes me feel like an idiot for the oversight.

When using variables for the parameters of `Telnet` the port needs to be an integer.  As such the solution was to force it by using `int(var)` and then it connected without issue.  The now working code is as follows.

```
import telnetlib

#Open file with list of switches
f = open ("C:\ProgramData\ports.txt")

#Telnet to each switch and configure it
for line in f:
    linePort = line[10:]
    lineIP = line[:-6]
    print "Getting running-config " + lineIP + " " + linePort
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(lineIP,int(linePort))
```